Custom Laravel top tickets but unique by player custom filters
I have two models: Ticket and Player.
The relationship between them is one-to-many: one player can have multiple tickets, and each ticket belongs to one player.
I need help retrieving the top tickets ordered by their score column, with the following constraints:

Each player can appear only once in the top tickets. If a player has multiple tickets, only his highest-scoring ticket should be included.
If multiple tickets have the same score by the same player, the ticket with the smaller ID should be prioritized.
The entire list of top tickets should be ordered by score and id if the score is the same for multiple tickets

Could you guide me on how to achieve this?
I already tried distinct to set in the select part of the query, but it did not resulted right.
I tried to user row_by function in mysql, and it worked out but also need if there is eloquent way of doing this?

Please add sample data and desired output to your question.

you can try something like this in your Tickets Model:
public function scopeTopTickets($query, $limit = 10)
{
    return $query->select('tickets.*')
        ->join('players', 'players.id', '=', 'tickets.player_id')
        ->groupBy('player_id')
        ->orderBy('score', 'desc')
        ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
        ->limit($limit);
}


This can not result, because when this query runs, an error occurs: SELECT list is not in the GROUP BY clause and contains a nonaggregated column.

The SELECT statement used with the GROUP BY clause must only contain columns that are either part of the GROUP BY clause or are used with an aggregate function. update the select to ->select('player_id')
